# $scope doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

The situation is like the code below. I want to change the value of $scope.pizzaList and $scope.selectedPizza when calling a function, but it seems not to change. I guess it is something with $scope's depth, but I'm not getting it. How to make these values get updated? Thanks in advance!

```
$scope.pizzaList = "some initial value";
$scope.selectedPizza = "some initial value";

$scope.setPizzaStatus = function (setStatus) {

    $http.post('url1', { userID: $scope.pizzaioloID, pizzaID: $scope.selectedPizzaID, statusNum: setStatus }).
    then(function(response) {

        $http.get("url2")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.pizzaList = response;
        });

        $http.get("url3")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.selectedPizza = response[0];
        }); 

    }, function(response) {

        console.log("Error");
    });
}   

$scope.pizzaList // doesn't get updated 
$scope.selectedPizza // doesn't get updated
```

Comment: You should also add the second function for error logging to the get of url2 & 3 to make sure they are being handled properly like you do with the post. Also, usually you put response.data or similar in your scope variable.

Answer (score 4):

Try use [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all):

```
$q.all([
    $http.get("url2"),
    $http.get("url3")
]).then(function(values){
    $scope.pizzaList = values[0];
    $scope.selectedPizza = values[1];//or values[1][0], It depends on data format;
}, function(error){
    //error processing;
});
```

Don't forget add `$q` service to controller;

Comment: Thanks! The problem wasn't with this code. The problem was that I wasn't return anything from backend, so the then part of $http.post never got executed.

Comment: @StefanPrifti anyway, I hope, it will be useful for You in future =)

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is written I would not expect the value of $scope.pizzaList to have changed between when you set it and when you evaluate it at the end.  It will only be changed when you call the setPizzaStatus() method, and even then it will only change after the post to url1 and the get from url2 have returned from your server.

Answer (score -2):

When you make a Get request, your Javascript code enters in "another task". So sometimes the current scope is not updated as expected. Try update the scope by calling "Apply", like this:

```
$http.get("url2")
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.pizzaList = response;
    $scope.$apply(); //or $scope.$applyAsync();
})
```

Comment: For those who downvoted this, why is calling $scope.$apply() a bad idea here?

Comment: Since you (and the OP) are using $http, angular is taking care of making sure the success callback is called within the angular context.  In certain versions of angular, this code would throw an exception (digest already in progress).

Comment: Ok thx.  So why is it not working? Is the best practice to use $q.all() or is something else going on? I have never had to use $scope.$apply() in my success callback to get things to work so I am a little confused.